# Vertical alignment of t-channel diagram with `tikz-feynman`

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-feynman

I want to align to Feynman-graphs drawn with [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](https://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/) ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) vertically.

As I see it, it would be aligned best if I could use the `inline` option on the label basline of the `z`. But since it is an edge and not a vertex, I don't know how.

(Must be compiled with `lualatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram[vertical'=a to b, baseline=(a)]{
        i1 [particle=a]
            -- [fermion] a [dot]
            -- [fermion] f1 [particle=c],
        a -- [boson, edge label'=z] b [dot],
        i2 [particle=b]
            -- [anti fermion] b
            -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=d]
    };
    \( \qquad \longrightarrow \qquad \)
    \feynmandiagram[horizontal=i to a, baseline=(i.base)]{
        i [particle=ab]
            -- a [blob],
        a
            -- [fermion] f1 [particle=c],
        a
            -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=d]
    };
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `($0.5*(a)+0.5*(b)$)` as baseline of the first diagram instead of `(a)`. This is the point between `(a)` and `(b)`, where the label `z` is located.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram[vertical'=a to b, baseline=($0.5*(a)+0.5*(b)$)]{
        i1 [particle=a]
            -- [fermion] a [dot]
            -- [fermion] f1 [particle=c],
        a -- [boson, edge label'=z] b [dot],
        i2 [particle=b]
            -- [anti fermion] b
            -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=d]
    };
    \( \qquad \longrightarrow \qquad \)
    \feynmandiagram[horizontal=i to a, baseline=(i.base)]{
        i [particle=ab]
            -- a [blob],
        a
            -- [fermion] f1 [particle=c],
        a
            -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=d]
    };
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```