# Alignment problem in feynman-tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

Consider the following code:

```
\feynmandiagram[vertical=a to b]{
l --[fermion] a --[fermion] i,
a --[photon] b,
j --[anti fermion] b --[anti fermion] k,
};
```

This gives the result as

[image]

However, what I wanted is

[image]

How can I draw the above diagram? Also I don't understand why `vertical=a to b command` is ignored.

Comment: are you using lualatex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352943/vertical-alignment-of-t-channel-diagram-with-tikz-feynman

Comment: @jsbibra I am using pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

with pdflatex the output

[image]

with lualatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram[vertical'=a to b, baseline=($0.5*(a)+0.5*(b)$)]{
        i1 [particle=a]
            -- [fermion] a [dot]
            -- [fermion] f1 [particle=c],
        a -- [boson, edge label'=z] b [dot],
        i2 [particle=b]
            -- [anti fermion] b
            -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=d]
    };
    \( \qquad \longrightarrow \qquad \)
    \feynmandiagram[horizontal=i to a, baseline=(i.base)]{
        i [particle=ab]
            -- a [blob],
        a
            -- [fermion] f1 [particle=c],
        a
            -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=d]
    };
\feynmandiagram[vertical=a to b]{
    l --[fermion] a --[fermion] i,
    a --[photon] b,
    j --[anti fermion] b --[anti fermion] k,
};
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```